# How to update my WinForms application from ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I finished this WinForms (Framework 4.0, Visual Studio 2012-2013) application and I have two(2) options to update it and I am stuck a little bit. Before explaining a bit more I also have a website built with ASP.NET that is also finished and from my website I want to update my application, I have two options:

1. Create an XML file with the file version that I will check when starting my application and compare the versions, I can do this but I have no idea how to update the application itself, let's say I do this and finally the application will check and compare version from user application with the XML file on the site and it will see that XML file version is newer than the version user uses.
   In that case what do I have to do to update my winforms application is it a software out there or is it from the Visual Studio any tweak.
2. Second option is to use the Click Once still I have no clue about it.

Conclusion is I think is better to use the first option and smoother but I just don't know how to update the files(assemblies) and everything else.

Comment: How is your WinForms app installed on the client machines?

Comment: My WinForms app is installed with an exe. file. Built with advanced studio installer under an exe. file and uplodaded on my website.

Comment: Then any updates you publish should have their own update(!) installer. Have your app look for that, download and run it.

Comment: And overwrite everything on the installation location folder on client machine ?

Comment: You're not supposed to do that manually. Create an update-enabled installer msi or exe, and have your app download and execute that.

Comment: ClickOnce is easy to deploy... You just have to link people to the `.application` file.

Comment: That's absurd... You know clickonce exists to solve your problem but rather than learn about it you conclude its best to just build your own thing from scratch. Come on, you are smarter than that.  Do some research.  I believe in you.

Answer (score 1):

You can not update your win app from asp.net directly but of course from desktop application you can create a separate class library which will compare your win app version with the XML file containing your updated file's location on web server. Now what you need to do is compare the version of win app with the XML file and download that new version.

Answer (score 0):

Use ClickOnce deployment!

I have a number of WPF and Windows Forms applications that are deployed with ClickOnce. What you do, is set a folder in your ASP.Net application as the publish location of your client application. Once installed from that location, it will check for updates and install automatically without you having to code for it.

This has proved to be far more reliable than when I tried to use InstallShield for the same purpose.